# Tower law in Kallenberg

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

In Kallenberg's probability text, Lemma 3.11 states what I think is related to the tower law.

> If $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent random variables in measurable spaces $S$ and $T$, and $f: S \times T \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable with $E(E|f(s,\eta)|)_{s=\xi}<\infty$, then $E f(\xi,\eta)=E(E(f(s,\xi))_{s=\xi}$.

This looks like the tower law (aka "smoothing") $E[E[f(X,Y) \mid X]]=E[f(X,Y)]$, which I have seen in other contexts, but I don't recall there being an independence assumption as there is in the above lemma. In general is there an independence requirement between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: A less ambiguous way to state the conclusion is that $Ef(\xi,\eta)=Eg(\xi)$ where the function $g$ is defined by $g(x)=Ef(x,\eta)$ for every $x$. Indeed this requires independence (and is not related to the tower property). For a proof, use Fubini on the definition of $Ef(\xi,\eta)$.

Comment: Should the last line in the question read $f(s, \nu)$ instead of $f(s \eta) $?

Comment: Thank you @Did. Would you mind explaining why this is not related to the [tower property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)?

Comment: Because this requires only independence and the joint distribution of $(\xi,\eta)$.

Comment: @Did Ok, thank you again!

Comment: Just my five cents: you can of course, relate this to the tower property through easily provable formula $E[f(\xi,\eta)\mid \xi] = E[f(s,\eta)]\big|_{s=\xi}$, but there is no need. The argument through the Fubini theorem, as suggested by @Did, is straightforward and does not need any notions deeper than the independence and product measures.

Comment: @zhoraster Thank you, that's sort of what I gathered; in particular, this result doesn't need the complicated notion of conditional expectation.